# How to consume HTTPS SOAP Webservice in .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, soap, https, azure-webjobs

I am developing an integration .NET Framework WebJob, that consists on serializing an .`xml` and sending the file info to a SOAP WebService given by the client. I have a class that works like an proxy that implements `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`, which allows me to actually consume the WebService.

Since the client webservice is in https, if I install the certificate locally, I can debug my service and it works fine. But when I deploy it to azure, it obviously gives me this error below.

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
[02/09/2021 11:12:16 > 559726: INFO]    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
```

My question is if its there some kind of implementation that I am missing? Is there a way to work around of actually needing to install the certificate locally? How can I do it in the cloud?

Here's my proxy code below:

```
namespace nav { 

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.8.3928.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="Logitude_Invoice_Integration_Binding", Namespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Logitude_Invoice_Integration")]
    public partial class Logitude_Invoice_Integration : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {
        
        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback ImportOrderOperationCompleted;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public Logitude_Invoice_Integration() {
            this.Url = ""; // populated by the clients soap Webservice URL
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public event ImportOrderCompletedEventHandler ImportOrderCompleted;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Logitude_Invoice_Integration:ImportOrder", RequestNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Logitude_Invoice_Integration", ResponseElementName="ImportOrder_Result", ResponseNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Logitude_Invoice_Integration", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        public void ImportOrder(Logitude p_xmlARInvoices1050, ref string p_txtResponseText, ref string p_txtResponseErrorText, ref string p_codeCreatedDocNo) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("ImportOrder", new object[] {
                        p_xmlARInvoices1050,
                        p_txtResponseText,
                        p_txtResponseErrorText,
                        p_codeCreatedDocNo});
            p_txtResponseText = ((string)(results[0]));
            p_txtResponseErrorText = ((string)(results[1]));
            p_codeCreatedDocNo = ((string)(results[2]));
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public System.IAsyncResult BeginImportOrder(Logitude p_xmlARInvoices1050, string p_txtResponseText, string p_txtResponseErrorText, string p_codeCreatedDocNo, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState) {
            return this.BeginInvoke("ImportOrder", new object[] {
                        p_xmlARInvoices1050,
                        p_txtResponseText,
                        p_txtResponseErrorText,
                        p_codeCreatedDocNo}, callback, asyncState);
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public void EndImportOrder(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, out string p_txtResponseText, out string p_txtResponseErrorText, out string p_codeCreatedDocNo) {
            object[] results = this.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
            p_txtResponseText = ((string)(results[0]));
            p_txtResponseErrorText = ((string)(results[1]));
            p_codeCreatedDocNo = ((string)(results[2]));
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public void ImportOrderAsync(Logitude p_xmlARInvoices1050, string p_txtResponseText, string p_txtResponseErrorText, string p_codeCreatedDocNo) {
            this.ImportOrderAsync(p_xmlARInvoices1050, p_txtResponseText, p_txtResponseErrorText, p_codeCreatedDocNo, null);
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public void ImportOrderAsync(Logitude p_xmlARInvoices1050, string p_txtResponseText, string p_txtResponseErrorText, string p_codeCreatedDocNo, object userState) {
            if ((this.ImportOrderOperationCompleted == null)) {
                this.ImportOrderOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnImportOrderOperationCompleted);
            }
            this.InvokeAsync("ImportOrder", new object[] {
                        p_xmlARInvoices1050,
                        p_txtResponseText,
                        p_txtResponseErrorText,
                        p_codeCreatedDocNo}, this.ImportOrderOperationCompleted, userState);
        }
        
        private void OnImportOrderOperationCompleted(object arg) {
            if ((this.ImportOrderCompleted != null)) {
                System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
                this.ImportOrderCompleted(this, new ImportOrderCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public new void CancelAsync(object userState) {
            base.CancelAsync(userState);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main options for using a certificate within App Services. Both use Key Vault to securely store the certificate within Azure.

The simplest option is going to be to add the certificate to your App Service account. Installed certificates can be found in the [SSL/TLS screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate) for your App Service. If you need to access it from inside your code, add an app setting named `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with the thumbprint of the certificate, which will be visible in the portal once you've uploaded it if you don't already know the value. The location of the cert in the file system depends on whether you are uploading the private or public cert and if you are on a Linux or Windows host:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-linuxwindows-containers

You can also store certificates in Key Vault directly and then retrieve them using a [Key Vault Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/security.keyvault.certificates-readme#retrieve-a-certificate).

```
var client = new CertificateClient(vaultUri: new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());
KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificateWithPolicy = client.GetCertificate("MyCertificate");
```